# Display loading circle when button is clicked in php website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

I'm new to programming in javascript and am having a lot of difficulty doing something I believe is simple. I have a loading circle that I want to display when an upload button is clicked (and also want my external php code to run to do image processing). Then, I want the loading screen to go away once the php page is done loading. I'm currently having trouble even getting the loading screen to show. I have the loading circle code in the style section of my header as so:

```
<head>
<style>
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #00ff00;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


</style>

</head>
```

Then, I have my upload button and the script in the body as so:

```
    <p class="text-center"> 

        <button  onclick="loadingCircle()"> Click to Upload! </button>
    </p> 
    <div id="loader" style="display:none;"></div> 
<script>
    function loadingCircle() {
        $("#loader").show();
        }

    </script>
```

Currently, when I click the upload button, no action is happening... any help is appreciated and apologies for the noobness.

Comment: what is error see console

Comment: Are you posting your form using Ajax? If not, then the page will be redirected to the form action and many browsers won't show animations etc while the new page (the upload target) is loading.

Comment: your given code seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jquery file https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or you can hide by using simple javascript:

```
<script>
    function loadingCircle() {
       document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: How wold I then hide all the other images,text, etc from the page so that only the loading circle is showing?

Comment: give id to <div id='hide-div'> then add one more line in javascript code

<script>
    function loadingCircle() {
document.getElementById('hide-div').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';
        }

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

the `$("#loader")` points to the fact that you are trying to use jQuery, which you have not included.

Include it from a cdn, and it should work